# WCF service selfhosting

Tags: wcf

I am creating a WCF service with self hosting. I have found the following error i.e.:

> The target assembly contains no service types. You may need to adjust the Code Access Security policy of this assembly.

The codes are as follows:

```
namespace MyJobs
{
   public interface IJobsSvc
   {
       [OperationContract]
       DataSet GetJobs();

       [OperationContract]
       Job GetJobInfo(int JobId);

       [OperationContract]
       List<Job> GetAllJobs();
    }
}

namespace MyJobs
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Job
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int JobId { get; set;}

        [DataMember]
        public string Description{get;set;}

        [DataMember]
        public int MinLevel { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int MaxLevel { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyJobs
{
    public class JobsSvc:IJobsSvc
    {
        #region IJobsSvc Members

        public System.Data.DataSet GetJobs()
        {
            string str = @"data source=PERSONAL-659BE4;database=practice;integrated security=true";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(str);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Job1",cn);
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;

        }

        public Job GetJobInfo(int JobId)
        {
            string str = @"data source=PERSONAL-659BE4;database=practice;integrated security=true";
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(str);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Job1 where JobId="+JobId,cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Job obj = new Job();
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                obj.JobId = JobId;
                obj.Description = dr[1].ToString();
                obj.MinLevel = Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]);
                obj.MaxLevel = Convert.ToInt32(dr[3]);
            }
            else
            {
                obj.JobId = -1;
            }
            return obj;
        }

        public List<Job> GetAllJobs()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

The app.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyJobs.Job">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyJobs.IJobsSvc">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/Jobs/MyJobs/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information,
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes,
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Comment: From your app.config: `<!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->`.  It looks like you've created a WCF Service Library.  If this is the case, you need to put the WCF configuration data in the App.config file of the application that is consuming the library, not in the App.config of the library.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `[ServiceContract]` attribute to your `IJobSvc` interface

**Update**

Create the behavior to expose the metadata.

```
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Then configure your service with this behavior:

```
  <service name="MyJobs.Job" behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior">
  <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyJobs.IJobsSvc">
```

Comment: Error changed to "WCF service host cant find any service meta data. This may cause the client app to run improperly. please check if meta data is emabled."

Comment: @AlokKumar, can you please post your wcf configuration file?

Comment: @AlokKumar, I do not see the config file.  Anyway, I suspect that you're missing the following:  `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />` within your service's behavior configuration

Comment: i am unable to add app.config file

Comment: @AlokKumar, what is the new error message? Unfortunately, without knowing what your configuration is, it is difficult to offer any further advice.

Comment: plz tell me how to send the config file otherwise give me your mailid and i will mail u..plz

Comment: @AlokKumar, you need to provide the shareable url :0)

Comment: I did you a favor and copy/pasted your config from pastebin to your original post here.

Comment: A dialog box with 3 tab i.e. service,status and metadata address but there is error in ststus

Comment: @AlokKumar, sounds like things are working. It also looks like you had a fun time getting dirty with WCF ;)

Comment: @Tung, u r r8..now its working..but now unable to consume it.

Comment: @Tung, I have attached the total code in the fillowing link..
http://pastebin.com/8cVKrqci

Comment: @AlokKumar, you should post the new problem that you are observing as a different question, since we are moving away from your original posted problem.  Furthermore, now we're delving into the realm of WPF, something I admittedly know very little about. Other SO users may be able to help you. Just remember to post your code, and the exception to make your question clear.  As long as you are not receiving an exception from your WCF call, I think you're good on the WCF side