# How to skip WCF Service Host Dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf

[image]

How can I skip this dialog when I run debug application, I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Is your project actually a WCF (service) project? It shouldn't complain if it isn't. If it is, you probably _want_ a service there, don't you?

Comment: Yes, it is."want a service there' ,  I dont know what you say. Please clerify . Thanks and best regards. I search this, some issue say that open tab WCF Options to check ..., but my visual miss this tab. I search how to show WCF tab, but it doesn't work

Comment: Again, if you really want to have a service running you need to make sure you properly expose one.
There are a couple of existing Q&A about this on SO already (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10054416/21567) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13626175/21567)).
Otherwise, you can can make VS [skip this check/message](http://stackoverflow.com/q/564541/21567).